# How to create table of contents using unstructured (the python package)

Tags: python, nlp

### tl;dr

How can I extract a clean table of contents from a pdf document that has hierarchical section headers using the [`unstructured`](https://unstructured.io/) package?

### Some more details

I have a pdf document that is multiple pages long. The text in the document is organised into multiple sections, each with a header/title. Each of these sections are potentially split up into subsections with their own header/title. These subsections can have subsubsections, etc.

The document does not have a table of contents page. How can I use the [`unstructured`](https://unstructured.io/) package to automatically extract a table of contents from my document? The table of contents should have the same hierarchy as the sections and subsections in my document.

### Example

If my document looks like this:

> **This is the title of section 1**
>
> Bla bla bla.
>
> **This is the title of subsection 1.1**
>
> More bla bla bla.
>
> **This is the title of subsubsection 1.1.1**
>
> More bla bla bla.
>
> **This is the title of subsection 1.2**
>
> More bla bla bla.
>
> **This is the title of section 2**
>
> Even more bla bla.

Then I would like to extract a table of contents from this that includes the hierarchy of headers. For example:

```py
{
    "This is the title of section 1": 0,
    "This is the title of subsection 1.1": 1,
    "This is the title of subsubsection 1.1.1": 2,
    "This is the title of subsection 1.2": 1,
    "This is the title of section 2": 0,
}
```

Where the number indicates the level of the header in the hierarchy.

Comment: Does it have to be done with the unstructured package?

Comment: Preferably but not necessarily.